# Django-Rest-Framework: Make A PUT Request to API

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, request, attributes

So I want to make a put request to change the content of a message in my chat/messaging app.

```
class MessageView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete', 'patch']
    queryset = Message.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MessageSerializer

    filter_backends = (
        django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,
        rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter, 
    )
    filter_fields = ['room']

class UserMessageView(MessageView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Message.objects.filter(canview__user=self.request.user)

    #get
    def get(self, request):
        hello_param = request.GET["helloParam"]

    #post
    def post(self, request):
        hello_param = request.POST["helloParam"]

    #put
    def put(self, request):
        hello_param = request.PUT["helloParam"]

    #patch
    def patch(self, request):
        hello_param = request.PATCH["helloParam"]

    #delete
    def delete(self, request):
        hello_param = request.DELETE["helloParam"]
```

This is the error I get:

> Request object has no attribute PUT

If You have any idea how to fix this please respond! :) Thank you!

Comment: use `request.data` or `request.POST` instead of `request.PUT`

Comment: If I do that I just get an error, how should the system know that its a PUT request if I do that?

Comment: so you mean replacing request.PUT['HelloParam'] would fix it or do I need to do something else?

Comment: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`

Comment: #put
    def put(self, request):
        request.data

Comment: You need to return a response in your function.. all the data sent to your endpoint are stored in `data` attribute. there is no `PUT` attribute [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data)

Comment: How do I return a response?

Comment: `return Response(data)`
follow the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/)